# What's the correct way to fill out volumes section in YAML for Airflow installation with Kubernetes Secrets?

Tags: yaml, airflow, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets, volumes

I'm trying to create an override.yaml to place my own values to my Airflow chart installation, however since I'm fairly new to YAML I can't seem to fill out the `volumes: []` and `volumeMounts: []` section of the values.yaml file correctly.

Use Case: I'm trying to mount .env files to a mountpath in my airflow containers though Kubernetes Secrets.

However, installation of airflow chart fails once I've placed this values in my YAML.

Can anyone please help how to properly fill out the volumes section? An example with these sections filled out would greatly help.

Thank you!

Here's what I've tried.

```
# Volumes for all airflow containers
volumes: []
    - name: varconn-secret
      secret:
        secretName: airflow-varconn-secret
        #items:
        #  - key: var.env
        #  - key: conn.env

# VolumeMounts for all airflow containers
volumeMounts: []
    - name: varconn-secret
      mountPath: /run/secrets/
        readOnly: True
```

Comment: As you've shown it, you have both an empty list `[]` and list items below that, which will result in a YAML parsing error.  Does deleting the `[]` help?  What is the actual error you're encountering?